# What are good techniques to describe eyes?

Tags: characters, technique, word-choice

I would like to describe the beautiful brown eyes of a character, much like a real-life friend of mine. Are there good techniques for describing eyes? How does one go about describing eyes in writing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is basically about getting other people to write the words for the OP.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! We're a Q&A site, and we have certain guidelines that define what kind of questions we do and don't take (there's a handy summary [here](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/875/writing-se-on-topic-summary)!). Specifically, we won't phrase (or rephrase) writing for you; that's much more asking somebody else to write a specific snippet -- which is less helpful as a resource to other writers :)

Comment: Seems more like a question for IPS. You writing IRL, right?

Comment: I think this question is about writing technique, unless we as a community are incapable of showing the creative process without telling the result.

Answer (score 3):

Without us seeing any particular shade of eyes, it will be pretty hard to help you! "Brown" is pretty generic. Find something (perhaps personal to you) that the shade reminds you of; the more poetic the better.

Another typical way out of this is to avoid any clinicality in describing a shade or shape, and talk about how the eyes make another character feel emotionally, what you know or imagine these brown eyes have seen, the experiences of your character (or friend) and their beautiful personality through the metaphor of what they have seen and done.

Comment: Stop answering off-topic questions.

Comment: @user57423 Once it is marked off-topic, I am not ABLE to answer it, and before it is closed for being off-topic, whether it is or is not is a matter of opinion. In MY opinion, it could be interpreted as an answerable question as far as providing a new writer some instruction, so I answered it. You are entitled to your opinion, I am entitled to mine, stop acting like you are the hall monitor. There is no rule that says I must believe it is going to be closed, before it is closed. And the only reason I frequent this site is to help beginning writers, so I'll *continue* to do that whenever I can.

Comment: When you answer questions that are extremely likely to get closed, your answers go to waste: here, for example, is a good answer that addresses the question behind the OP's particular question; it could help many people. But because the question gets closed, few people would see your answer. Editing the question to make it better, as you've done now, is beneficial both to the OP  and to anyone else who might face a similar problem. Perhaps, when you see the good question hiding within the about-to-be-closed question, you can edit it straight away, avoiding the argument that's being had here?

Comment: I voted to reopen, btw.

Comment: @user57423 I notice you too answered at least one question that later got closed: https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/40370/14704

Answer (score 0):

There's various ways one can do this, but in contemporary settings, chocolate is a decent simile to compare them to. Copper or burnished metal also works, or simply describe them as beautiful brown eyes. Maybe the shape is unusual, or the glimmer in them. Colour alone is so limiting when it comes to the beauty of eyes. Think outside the box.